# Why is this the default datetime in Python?

Tags: python, datetime

I tried on an online Python interpreter

```
from datetime import datetime
print(datetime.fromtimestamp(0))
```

And it predictably prints `1970-01-01 00:00:00`. I know this is the Unix Epoch. However, I tried it on my machine and it prints `1969-12-31 19:00:00`. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: What is the timezone setting for the machine you're running the code on? Is it `-05:00`?

Comment: Try `import timezone; print(datetime.fromtimestamp(0).astimezone(zoneinfo.ZoneInfo('UTC')))`. You should see `1970-01-01 00:00:00+00:00`

Answer (score 1):

Note that the [epoch base time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), so unless your time-zone matches that perfectly, you'll get a slightly different time, adjusted according to your time-zone offset in 1969/1970.

This is why you'll often see times listed on sites or filesystems as December 31, 1969, as that's what any systems east of the UTC meridian will show for a "0" time.

Answer (score 1):

this is really asking why does that function apply the time zone. The implementation of that method uses the libc's *localtime* function, the *man page* of which say this:

> The localtime() function converts the calendar time timep to broken-down time representation, expressed relative  to  the user's specified timezone.  The function acts as if it called tzset(3) and sets the external variables tzname with information about the current timezone

The system call is automatically applying the local time zone, if it's known. Some hosts have their timezone set to UTC.